# Qt. Объявлять элементы формы внутри класса или в конструкторе?

Tags: c++, qt, классы, объявление

Смотрю примеры кода в Qt. Есть ли разница объявлять элементы формы внутри класса или в конструкторе? Если да, то при каких ситуациях следует объявлять элементы в классе вот так:

`

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow();
private:
    QMenu *fileMenu;
    QMenu *editMenu;
    QMenu *formatMenu;
    QMenu *helpMenu;
    QAction *cutAct;
}`
```

А при каких уже непосредственно в конструкторе вот так:

```
    void MainWindow::createMenus()
{

    QMenu* fileMenu;
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));

    QAction *quitAct = fileMenu->addAction(tr("&Quit"),this, QApplication::quit);
    quitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit from the application"));
    quitAct->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Q);

    QMenu* helpMenu;
    helpMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Help"));

    QAction *aboutAct = helpMenu->addAction(tr("&About"), this, &MainWindow::about);
    aboutAct->setStatusTip(tr("Show the application's About box"));
    aboutAct->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_A);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Когда нужны ссылки на эти элементы - объявляйте в классе. Когда создал и забыл - в конструкторе.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ). Как я понимаю ссылки будут нужны если этот элемент как то изменяется от действий других элементов?

Comment: @LimarDeWills скорее от действия пользователя. Пользователь написал строку в поле ввода и нажал на кнопку сохранить. В обработчике кнопки нужна ссылка на текст в поле ввода. Ссылка на кнопку может быть нужна если мы будем делать её активной или выключенной. Ссылки на лэйауты, лейблы, меню не нужны обычно

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответы)